# How can we get html of Onenote page. I am trying through Onenote.analyzePage() but is giving null

Tags: office-js, office-addins, onenote

I am using the following to get page HTML, but it is not working. Please if someone can suggest.

```
function run() {
  try {
    OneNote.run(function (ctx) {
      // Get the current page.         
      var page = ctx.application.getActivePage();
      var pageContent = page.analyzePage();
      page.load('webUrl');
      return ctx.sync().
        then(function () {
          console.log(pageContent);
          console.log(page.webUrl);
        });
    });
  } catch (error) {

  }
}
```

Comment: What do you get if you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(pageContent));`?

Comment: I put pageContent in console and it shows m_isLoaded: true
m_type: 0
m_value: null
value: null

Comment: This might be a bug. Please raise this as an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.

Comment: Thanks will do that. One more help needed apart from this, di you know how I can load user info in one note web addin, there seems no straightforward way